# Push value to anonymous array

Tags: javascript

In my code there is this section :

```
//config.tls.ca can be a String or and Array of String
if (config.tls.ca && !Array.isArray(config.tls.ca)) 
  config.tls.ca = [].push(config.tls.ca);
```

I realized that after it : `config.tls.ca = 1`

Why does this happen ?

```js
document.write([].push("Hello World"));
```

Comment: Just start from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: `config.tls.ca = [config.tls.ca];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

You're pushing one item into an empty array, so the new length of the array is `1`, which is returned from `push` and assigned to `.ca`. The array itself vanishes into the aether, since it's not assigned to anything.

There's no reason to write such code; you would do this instead:

```
config.tls.ca = [config.tls.ca];
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew the `[config.tls.ca]` syntax was valid :)

Comment: It's a simple [Array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).